# Error: Could not find or load main class org.red5.server.Bootstrap

Tags: java, bash, maven

I am trying to install https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server (or https://github.com/Red5/red5-server):

The instructions [here](https://github.com/ant-media/LiveVideoBroadcaster#step-1-get-a-media-server) tells, just download and run `./red5.sh` but I guess something more is required.

ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/red5-server/src/main/server$ `bash red5.sh`

> Running on  Darwin
>   Starting Red5
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.red5.server.Bootstrap

Comment: You are building the app from scratch? You may try downloading the latest built version at http://antmedia.io